# Method Not Allowed - The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-restful

I'm trying to build a python flask application, but I'm facing an issue when I try to submit form data to the python method.

The issue that the server is throwing is "Method Not Allowed".

> HTML CODE

```
<h1>Submit the Link</h1>
    <form action="/submit_article" method="POST" name="form">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="description">Name</label>
                {{ form.description }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="link">Link</label>
                {{ form.link }}
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> PYTHON METHOD (submit_article)

```
@app.route('/submit_article', methods=['POST'])
def submit_article():
  form = UploadForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    data = {
        "_id": form.link.data,
        "description": form.description.data,
        "user": current_user.username,
        "time": datetime.datetime.now()
    }

    try:
        if((app.config['NEWS_COLLECTION'].insert(data))):
            flash("Link added successfully", category="success")
            return redirect(request.args.get("new") or url_for("new"))

    except DuplicateKeyError:
        flash("Article link already exists in the Database", category="error")
        return render_template("submit_article.html")

  return render_template('submit_article.html', title='login', form=form)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method is not allowed because you have only specified 'POST' in your `methods` list. But whenever you try to visit this URL it will send the 'GET' request. 'POST' request will be sent when you click a button but initially it will visit the page via 'GET' request.

So replace `methods=['POST']` with `methods=['POST', 'GET']` and your problem will be resolve.

Comment: Thanks @Hassan Mehmood, it worked. :)